# Как получить куки для запроса?

Tags: python, requests, cookie, header

Запрос не проходит без кук, но вопрос в том как их получить.

Вот сам запрос (да, здесь куки должны указываться в хедерах):

```
DatesList = requests.get(
            "https://central.myvisit.com/CentralAPI/SearchAvailableDates?maxResults=31&serviceId={}&startDate={}".format(
                ServiceId, datetime.datetime.now().date()),
            headers={
                "accept-language": "en",
                "application-api-key": "8640a12d-52a7-4c2a-afe1-4411e00e3ac4",
                "application-name": "myVisit.com v3.5",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                              "Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/93.0.0.0 (Edition Yx GX)",
                "cookie": "mvcnm=Israel; mvcid=1; mvcc=il; mvlng=en; rbzid=0g14Zc2vHAe9g2zQBWibW+MlbbSimlZbRbzqYj6VcyQOL4L0vdb39bt+srcQ+02shdWGhKtKxTuhkLWBHvjgBI/YM+Dwrg7vpDsAxhkek8XWkQocVyjyI2kxLzI9gRJpK8xkHVwzlt5Bzw5o20MxVzEal21PQ1v0RKDT3FoiFyvKvisn2DjmIt4/J8xxP3YMkZm5gb+bq0cQd19FLi5mi1Y+83diXUBXLLYfz8VVTpSD0yqkN0slFjAkkLEP4BqVglJ8NpMYTTIPUkVkDGwvfw==; GCLB=CKnzm7iytoCwSg; ARRAffinity=ba860f6aba1d259d66070249e7c8bfb5f99bc67f442131118e3083cc3ccdcb93; ARRAffinitySameSite=ba860f6aba1d259d66070249e7c8bfb5f99bc67f442131118e3083cc3ccdcb93; _ga=GA1.2.714197549.1672273705; _gid=GA1.2.760777199.1672273705; _gat=1; CentralJWTCookie=jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im92VFc2ckQ4ZmExM1V1cUdKT1BQNkFqa2NMQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vY2VudHJhbC5xbm9teS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vY2VudHJhbC5xbm9teS5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE2NzIyNzM3MTEsImV4cCI6MTY3MjI3NzMxMSwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiIyYmVjYzUyOS1lODRmLTRhMzItYTc4YS0zYTJmMDY5YmJiMjMiLCJ1aWQiOiJVM2c5dDZRM2IzblpWcWc0bkFjeG13PT0ifQ.QK3BxHVKobs1prnioNsJKuHCs1Hce5O5xdVn6kIbDGvAII1M-ctV3BIJ5yzTVDcHChbt1ZG4NLoMkxJHwyJKQ4Cl3FWnOzrcTRP9CZ1yPTFJmOQcmpQlD7i_XCAZ-zVVRNjieZvRjCAJeq0hRwUBpOs3B8PUyPEnefivdimkL7rTjk0sFCfPIVk6GugsTv7Cew46wqv8L4ftUL-OX_IsEywCd9lzMHooftY_xWp3xwPbcE_hRHGSPqJ8Ap_g1KrQjvk5W6eV1Yl1xS2qCKluKKJcq_nF68FP_RTejMT_t86Re3lUTVE1uzF_Khn8qsON9hsy2mekFAv94e_LSFjDsQ",
            })
```

Куки имеют свойство протухать и я никак не могу разобраться как получать новые. Возможно нужно создать сессию и получать куки из других запросов.

Comment: ```Возможно нужно создать сессию  и получать куки из других запросов``` - мне почему то кажется отличной идеей :)

Comment: Владимир Клыков, я попробовал так сделать, но я не понимаю, как мне получить их из запросов...

Comment: Вероятно получив описание апи или проведя анализ сайта? или вы хотите чтобы мы вам проанализировали сайт?

Comment: Анализ я провёл, куки только отправляются, а не получаются.

Answer (score 0):

В целом всё должно быть просто. Я в своё время оборачивал все запросы через объект Session - и работало. Попробуйте так же.

```
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("https://central.myvisit.com/CentralAPI/SearchAvailableDates?maxResults=31&serviceId={}&startDate={}".format(
            ServiceId, datetime.datetime.now().date()),
        headers={
            "accept-language": "en",
            "application-api-key": "8640a12d-52a7-4c2a-afe1-4411e00e3ac4",
            "application-name": "myVisit.com v3.5",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                          "Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/93.0.0.0 (Edition Yx GX)",
            "cookie": "mvcnm=Israel; mvcid=1; mvcc=il; mvlng=en; rbzid=0g14Zc2vHAe9g2zQBWibW+MlbbSimlZbRbzqYj6VcyQOL4L0vdb39bt+srcQ+02shdWGhKtKxTuhkLWBHvjgBI/YM+Dwrg7vpDsAxhkek8XWkQocVyjyI2kxLzI9gRJpK8xkHVwzlt5Bzw5o20MxVzEal21PQ1v0RKDT3FoiFyvKvisn2DjmIt4/J8xxP3YMkZm5gb+bq0cQd19FLi5mi1Y+83diXUBXLLYfz8VVTpSD0yqkN0slFjAkkLEP4BqVglJ8NpMYTTIPUkVkDGwvfw==; GCLB=CKnzm7iytoCwSg; ARRAffinity=ba860f6aba1d259d66070249e7c8bfb5f99bc67f442131118e3083cc3ccdcb93; ARRAffinitySameSite=ba860f6aba1d259d66070249e7c8bfb5f99bc67f442131118e3083cc3ccdcb93; _ga=GA1.2.714197549.1672273705; _gid=GA1.2.760777199.1672273705; _gat=1; CentralJWTCookie=jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im92VFc2ckQ4ZmExM1V1cUdKT1BQNkFqa2NMQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vY2VudHJhbC5xbm9teS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vY2VudHJhbC5xbm9teS5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE2NzIyNzM3MTEsImV4cCI6MTY3MjI3NzMxMSwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiIyYmVjYzUyOS1lODRmLTRhMzItYTc4YS0zYTJmMDY5YmJiMjMiLCJ1aWQiOiJVM2c5dDZRM2IzblpWcWc0bkFjeG13PT0ifQ.QK3BxHVKobs1prnioNsJKuHCs1Hce5O5xdVn6kIbDGvAII1M-ctV3BIJ5yzTVDcHChbt1ZG4NLoMkxJHwyJKQ4Cl3FWnOzrcTRP9CZ1yPTFJmOQcmpQlD7i_XCAZ-zVVRNjieZvRjCAJeq0hRwUBpOs3B8PUyPEnefivdimkL7rTjk0sFCfPIVk6GugsTv7Cew46wqv8L4ftUL-OX_IsEywCd9lzMHooftY_xWp3xwPbcE_hRHGSPqJ8Ap_g1KrQjvk5W6eV1Yl1xS2qCKluKKJcq_nF68FP_RTejMT_t86Re3lUTVE1uzF_Khn8qsON9hsy2mekFAv94e_LSFjDsQ",
        })
session.get("https://новый_запрос")
session.get("https://ещё_запрос")
```

При использовании сессии куки должны автоматически сохраняться и обновляться, главное - убедиться, что **все** запросы обёрнуты в эту сессию.

Comment: Не всё так просто, пробовал так сделать, не получилось. Куки отправляются, а откуда они берутся-непонятно.

Comment: Обычно куки устанавливаются сервером с помощью хедера Set-Cookie. В Вашем случае сервер эти заголовки не присылает - возможно, потому, что скрипт не может полностью имитировать поведение пользователя. Попробуйте открыть сайт в обычном браузере и посмотреть трафик через MITM-прокси типа Fiddler, OWASP-ZAP или Charles - там будут видны заголовки Set-Cookie, а также все заголовки, которые отправляет клиент, и запрашиваемые им страницы/ресурсы. Может быть, сервер ожидает ещё каких-то действий пользователя.